# Devise and form objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Current, i'm using the nested_attributes_for with my Devise model as follow.

My models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  has_one :user_profile, inverse_of: :user, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_profile
end
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

class UserProfile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :user_profile
end
```

My **[devise custom controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers)**

```
 class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

 .....

 protected

def configure_sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, user_profile_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :birth_date, :phone, :cellphone, :gender]])
end

def configure_account_update_params
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, user_profile_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :birth_date, :phone, :cellphone, :gender]])
end

end
```

Everything is working, but I'm trying to clean my code and refactor to the **[form object](https://forum.upcase.com/t/form-objects/2267)** pattern to create both a Devise user and a user_profile in one step. But I don't know how can I do that with Devise. Should I use the custom controller? Create a new Controller?

Anyone that have applied this can help me?